# Insert subtotal for Excel spreadsheets

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I have some irregular data (e.g. I have 5 groups of data, each group occupies different amount of rows) and I am wondering if there is a way to use Python to add subtotal to all of my spreadsheets, breaking at each group change.

Since row amount is irregular for each group, I tried inserting empty row at each change and adding a subtotal. However, I am unable to do a sum for each change or a grand total without using hard code (specify on the row number, which changes for every spreadsheet).

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added code I am working on

```py
for num in range (8, ws.max_row+1):
    if ws['E'+str(num)].value == ws['L1'].value:
        ws['L'+str(num)]='=SUMIF($A$'+str(ws[num])+':$A$'+str(ws[ws.max_row])+',LEFT(A'+str(ws[num])+',6),$E$'+str(ws[num])+':$E$'+str(ws[ws.max_row])+')'
    num+=1
```

Comment: Post the code you are currently running, which does not yet do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add a column to each list that can help you categorize them? that way you can do a =SUMIF based on the categorized names. here's a code snipit and an image to reference:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,B15,C:C)
```

the formula calculates the left table (dogs).

[image]

as you can see the totals wont be added if the category is mentioned. also, all three tables are irregular so it will add up regardless of length.

Comment: in theory, you could just combine all three tables at this point and just have one subtotal table that sorts everything for you.

Comment: I am actually stuck on trying to insert an empty row at each change, but this sounds like it would work. Thanks!

Comment: So ur stuck at inserting an empty row programmatically? Please share your code.

Comment: Thanks Manny, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580054/python-openpyxl-insert-row-at-each-value-change
I couldn't post Python formatting under comment.

Comment: I actually managed to figure out how to insert row, took me awhile! Will test SUMIF today.