# Python Openpyxl Insert row at each value change

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am attempting to use Python to insert an empty row at each change, for instance:

Original Workbook:

```
A
A
A
B
B
C
```

Outcome:

```
A
A
A

B
B

C
```

Code I am working on:

```py
    num=2
    while num < 13:
        if ws['A'+str(num)].value != ws['A'+str(num+1)].value:
            ws.insert_rows(num+1)
        elif ws['A'+str(num)].value == ws['A'+str(num+1)].value or ws['A'+str(num)].value == '':
            pass
        num+=1
```

Output I currently get is

```
A
A
A



B
B
C
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: SOLVED! In a weird way.

```py
num=2
while num < 13:
    if ws['A'+str(num)].value == ws['A'+str(num+1)].value:
        pass
    elif ws['A'+str(num)].value == ws['J'+str(num)].value:
        pass
    elif ws['A'+str(num)].value != ws['A'+str(num+1)].value:
        ws.insert_rows(num+1)
    num+=1
```

Comment: Your code doesn't take into consideration that rows will change after each insertion. Tip: it's usual for this kind of operation to start at the bottom and work upwards.

Comment: Hi Charlie, I managed to "solve" it, but in the weirdest way possible. I tried
```python
elif ws['A'+str(num)].value == '':
pass
```
for some reason, Python is not recognizing empty rows as ''.

Comment: There is no easy definition of an empty cell.

Comment: Yup, took a rough ride but glad I managed to figure it out! Thanks for your help though. Just for my own learning, how should I approach this if I want to do it backwards? I know that ws.max_row will be my last row and ws['A1'] is my first, but if I am to do in in range, I am not sure how to tackle.

Comment: How about `reversed(list(ws.iter_rows(min_row=13)))`? Avoid Excel-style coordinates for this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

How about to write the code a little bit more tidy. 1st read the input, then find the rows with differences, finally add the rows and save the wb:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('example.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

values = [cell.value for cell in ws['A']]
diffs = [i for i in range(1, len(values)) if values[i] != values[i - 1]]
[ws.insert_rows(i+1) for i in reversed(diffs)]

wb.save('out.xlsx')
```